# Why do we need electronics?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avionics):

> Avionics are the electronic systems used on aircraft, artificial satellites, and spacecraft.
>   Avionic systems include communications, navigation, the display and management of multiple systems, and the hundreds of systems that are fitted to aircraft to perform individual functions. These can be as simple as a searchlight for a police helicopter or as complicated as the tactical system for an airborne early warning platform.

Why do we need [electronics](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronics)? Also, should it be synonimized to avionics?

Comment: I don't know how the tag is used, but a passenger's "electronic device" that needs to be switched off for departure would not constitute avionics.

Answer (score 2):

I've retagged two of these away (The remaining one is [the question about EFBs and paper charts](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/254/do-pilots-using-an-electronic-flight-bag-need-to-carry-paper-charts), and I think we could safely retag that one away too, but it's more of a gray area).

I agree with roe that we probably don't want to synonym [electronics](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronics) --> [avionics](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avionics) because we should probably have a tag for "personal electronic devices" that passengers might be using inaddition to the "aviation electronics" used for flight.

A [personal-electronic-devices](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-electronic-devices) or [passenger-electronic-devices](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passenger-electronic-devices) tag might make sense instead of just plain [electronics](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electronics), but until we have more questions of that sort it's a little hard to say.

Comment: I think that "portable" electronic devices is the official term in the US, and I agree that the electronics tag should be done away with.  The remaining question should be both EFB and PED in my mind.